# Django first migration issue

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Using PyCharm and following a step-by-step guide for setting up a cookiecutter Django project. Can't seem to get past the migrate command.

This is my first time using the cookiecutter project template and I haven't had issues before when creating projects from scratch. Not sure what the issue is but it looks like it may be related to the `INSTALLED_APPS`, but I haven't modified any of the files from the template.

Error is listed below:

> "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3\bin\runnerw64.exe"
>   C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
>   2018.3\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" migrate C:/Users/willi/PycharmProjects/fishgutz Tracking file by folder
>   pattern:  migrations Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
>   2018.3\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 52, in 
>       run_command()   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
>       run_module(manage_file, None, '**main**', True)   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 205, in run_module
>       return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)   File
>   "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 96, in _run_module_code
>       mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:/Users/willi/PycharmProjects/fishgutz\manage.py", line 30, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 371, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 365, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 216, in fetch_command
>       klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 36, in load_command_class
>       module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))   File
>   "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector   File
>   "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\autodetector.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner   File
>   "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\questioner.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       from .loader import MigrationLoader   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py",
>   line 9, in 
>       class MigrationRecorder:   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py",
>   line 22, in MigrationRecorder
>       class Migration(models.Model):   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
>   line 100, in **new**
>       app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
>   line 244, in get_containing_app_config
>       self.check_apps_ready()   File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
>   line 127, in check_apps_ready
>       raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
>
> Expected: postgres database configures and I can then runserver

Answer (score 0):

Are you using separated settings module? If you are, you must `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<your_settings_module>`

For example, when your settings separated by`prod/settings/local.py` and `prod/settings/deploy.py`

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=prod.settings.local`

or

`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=prod.settings.deploy`

Comment: the settings modules are indeed separated but that does not seem to be the fix.  I ran the export commands but received similar error messages.

Comment: @Wizumz give me your tutorial link.

Comment: https://joshuahunter.com/posts/using-cookiecutter-to-jumpstart-a-django-project-on-windows-with-pycharm/#cookiecutter

Comment: @Jongjin Jo I added an additional environment variable; CELERY_BROKER_URL and it appears like the migrate command is calculating a bit more but still produces a very similar error message. Not sure if that helps at all but maybe the env vars aren't setup entirely?

Comment: @Wizumz That error means django can not find settings module. Check your Pycharm django settings. Other vars has no relation.

Comment: I redid the process but chose NOT to include Celery and the migration and server ran successfully.  I believe that app was not set up in entirety and was throwing off the project. To avoid continued headache, I chose to exclude it for now. Thank you for the help @Yongjin Jo!

Answer (score 0):

I redid the process but chose NOT to include Celery and the migration and server ran successfully. I believe that app was not set up in entirety and was throwing off the project. To avoid continued headache, I chose to exclude it for now in the new setup. Thank you for the help @Yongjin Jo!